# Easiest way to copy transformations to another object

Tags: objects, transforms

I try to switch to blender from C4D. Now I have a question.

When I parent one object to another I often want to copy the transformation to the child object(s).
In Cinema 4D there is a command called "Reset Transform" which is pretty common and very prominent in the UI. I use it all the time.
In Blender the best way I could figure out to achieve that is by adding a "Copy Transformation" constraint, chose the parent object then apply visual transform and then delete the constraint.

Thats very laborious so I thought there must be an easier way to do that. First I tried it with the cursor (selection to cursor) but that doesn't affect the rotation, right?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it answers correctly but you can select the child, then shift select the parent, then in the N panel, put your mouse over the Location and right click > Copy All to Selected? You can also activate the Copy Attributes addon and Ctrl C > Copy Location

Comment: Another way to parent is via the relations panel in object properties. I find this handy for parenting a  new object (which has identity transform)  Select  parent  to "snap" it to the transform of parent.  Akin to without inverse option in ctl-p options., but perhaps easier to change parent.

Answer (score 2):

Then you add the parent relationship, an additional transformation is applied, called [Parent Inverse](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#:%7E:text=the%20Outliner%20editor.-,Parent%20Inverse,Parent%20Inverse%20matrix%20is%20updated.):

> Blender can assign a parent without moving the child object. This is
> achieved via a hidden matrix called the Parent Inverse matrix, which
> sits between the transform of the parent and the child

If you don't want this offset - you can remove it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> **Clear Parent Inverse**.  After doing this, offset will be moved to regular transforms, and if you clear this regular transforms, object will be moved to its parent (as it should be, because coordinates of objects are calculated from its parents).

So then use:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> - to move object to parent coordinates
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - to match rotation to parent's one
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - clears scale data if it is necessary